# Shouldn't it be Jacobian Descent?

Tags: gradient-descent, jacobian

Whenever we have a multiclass prediction the classifier generates a vector output. Per the definition of a [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) we are actually taking Jacobian steps towards a local minimum - so should it technically be called Jacobian Descent?

Answer (score 2):

No.

Although it is a multi-class classification problem, the loss is still a single number, not a vector.

We use cross entropy to convert a vector output to a single number.

[This](https://github.com/rasbt/python-machine-learning-book/blob/master/faq/softmax_regression.md) is a very good tutorial I suggest to read.

---

Here is an example from this tutorial: suppose we have 3 classes and 4 data points. The model output is

[image]

And the ground truth is

[image]

Cross entropy is

[image]

And final loss is sum of this length 4 cross entropy vector.

Comment: Thanks, one quick clarification.. suppose we a multi-layer neural net, is it fair to say that the middle layers have vector loss? and therefore we are performing Jacobian updates?

Comment: No. All the numbers in the middle layer are "weights", back prop is just a way to calculate the gradient respect to one single loss. @A.D